# Can I lock certain blocks within a Mailchimp template?

Tags: email, templates, mailchimp

I'm using the Mailchimp template builder and dragging and setting up various blocks.

Once the marketing team use the templates for their emails, is there a way of preventing certain blocks from being editable/removable?

Comment: Could you explain what you do mean by editable blocks? How can they manipulate them?

Comment: I'm referring to these: https://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/content-blocks/about-content-blocks

They're used when building the initial template. But also, when you assign a template to use with a campaign, the template editor opens up, allowing the user to edit/remove any of the blocks as they wish from the initial template.

Would be good if some can be selected to not be editable at that stage.